# Create random URL to a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a React component named `Auction` which I wanna render with a uniq URL everytime it's rendered,

so I can share the URL for this specific auction.
I'm using `react-router-dom`.

I have a function to create a random string:

```
const generateRandomString = () => Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
```

Which I wanna use as the `path` in the `react-router-dom` syntax like so:

```
<Route exact path={`/${generateRandomString()}`} render={() => <Auction />} 
/>
```

But this doesn't work. When I print `window.location.href` in the component it shows

> http://localhost:3000/?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can miss slash in route path.

```js
<Route exact path={ "/" + generateRandomString()} render={() => <Auction />} />
```

Comment: I just noticed it too but the same result. Edited the question with this correction

Comment: Can you share your code on codesandbox  or similar platform as minimal reproducible example ? It can help us to find a bug.